# f# interface with type constraint infinite when unifying

Tags: f#

I'm having problems getting an interface with type constraints to work generically.

Here's the type

```
type LeftistHeap<'a when 'a : comparison> =
...
    interface IHeap<LeftistHeap<'a>, 'a> with
...
        member this.Insert (x : 'a) = LeftistHeap.insert x this
```

and the interface

```
type IHeap<'a when 'a : comparison> =
    inherit System.Collections.IEnumerable
    inherit System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>
...
type IHeap<'c, 'a when 'c :> IHeap<'c, 'a> and 'a : comparison> =
    inherit IHeap<'a>
...
    abstract member Insert : 'a -> 'c
```

this code works no problem

```
let insertThruList l h  =
    List.fold (fun (h' : LeftistHeap<'a>) x -> h'.Insert  x  ) h l
```

but if I try to genralize the code for the interface

```
let insertThruList l h  =
    List.fold (fun (h' : IHeap<_,'a>) x -> h'.Insert  x  ) h l
```

I get this error at h'.Insert

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>   'b
>   but given a
>   IHeap<'b,'a>
>   The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''b' and 'IHeap<'b,'a>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler's right: you're trying to use a `'c` where you need an `IHeap<'c,_>`.  Since `'c :> IHeap<'c,_>`, one solution is just to insert an upcast:

```
let insertThruList l h =
    List.fold (fun (h' : IHeap<_,_>) x -> h'.Insert  x :> _) h l
```

Alternatively, you can indicate that you don't want the input to be (exactly) an `IHeap<_,_>`, but instead some particular subtype:

```
let insertThruList l h =
    List.fold (fun (h' : #IHeap<_,_>) x -> h'.Insert x) h l
```

This is probably what you really want (the type is more specific).  This is equivalent to the more verbose definition:

```
let insertThruList<'c,'a when 'a : comparison and 'c :> IHeap<'c,'a>> l h =
    List.fold (fun (h' : 'c) x -> h'.Insert x) h l
```

Comment: The flexible type indicator comes to the rescue.
List.fold (fun (h' : #IHeap<_,'a>) x -> h'.Insert  x  ) h l
Thanks!

Comment: On to the next problem. It seems this does not work when the constrained type interface is part of a tuple. Example: (fun (x : (#IHeap<_,'a> * 'a list)) ->
Same "infinte when unifying" problem.

Comment: @Jack - could you give a more complete example?  I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I was just preparing to make a stripped-down project that replicates the problem. Should have it done shortly (baring too many interuptions).

Comment: I isolated the problem to an unboxing issue

let x1 = box (tuple l)
let x2 : #IHeap<_,_> * list<'a> = unbox x1

...and #IHeap<_,_> highlighted with Error 2 Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'IHeap<'a,'b>' for a type inference variable. The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and 'IHeap<'a,'b>' Consider adding further type constraints

Comment: @Jack - sorry, that's still not enough for me to repro.  Could you include a complete self-contained example?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this https://github.com/jackfoxy/DebugFlexHeapTupleSolution I think I'm trying to do something impossible and I have yet to think of a solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

will this work for your case?

```
let insertThruList l (h : 'T when 'T :> IHeap<'T, 'a> )  =
    List.fold (fun (h' : 'T) x -> h'.Insert  x  ) h l
```